# Microsolf Excel formula required

Tags: excel-formula

I need to measure the performance of task completed per job. i am currently using formula:

```
=COUNTIF(H3:N3,"DONE")/COUNTA($H$2:$N$2).
```

It gives me 100% when text in each field is `DONE`.

Few tasks are not required to be performed for each job, and needs to be left blank. That time i do not get 100%. Please help.

Comment: You need `isblank` function. [docs](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isblank-function)

Comment: Can you please explain how do I use this formula.

Comment: I think I will, if you show me the structure of your table.

Comment: Am Sorry am a newbie to this site, not sure how can I share my Excel... For execution of one job there are 7 tasks to be completed. So I have added the tasks in Excel column H / I / J / K / L/ M & N, as and when the tasks are completed, I mention DONE. In column O, there's formula to calculate the percentage completed. =COUNTIF(H3:N3,"DONE")/COUNTA($H$2:$N$2). If I mention done in every row then I get 100%.

Comment: Why are you not using ` =COUNTIF(H3:N3,"DONE")/COUNTA($H$3:$N$3)`

Comment: Hi Mrig.. I need to leave few cells blanks for certain jobs as those are "Not Applicable". In such cases still I need the percentage to show 100%. Which formula do I use then?

Comment: Where are you leaving blanks, in row3 or row2?

Comment: Row 2 ( column - H/ I/ J/ K/ L/ M & N) all are filled as DONE and the result is 100%. Row 3 ( column - H/ I/ J/ K/ L/ M - DONE & column - N will be NA) I still need this to show as 100%

Comment: Use `=COUNTIF($H3:$N3,"DONE")/COUNTA($H3:$N3)` formula

Comment: I tried this formula... it works only when I leave the cell blank. but when I mention "Not Available" it does not give me 100%.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter following formula in `Cell O2`

```
=COUNTIF(H2:N2,"DONE")/(COUNTA(H2:N2)-COUNTIF(H2:N2,"Not Available"))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]